# Why connect `QThread::finished` signal to `QObject::deleteLater`?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I read this in the Qt 5.15 documentation for [`QThread::finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished):

> When this signal is emitted, the event loop has already stopped running. No more events will be processed in the thread, except for deferred deletion events. This signal can be connected to `QObject::deleteLater()`, to free objects in that thread.

However, in [another section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop) of the documentation, it says that

> Calling `delete` on a QObject from a thread other than the one that *owns* the object (or accessing the object in other ways) is unsafe, **unless you guarantee that the object isn't processing events at that moment** [emphasis mine].

If I'm understanding this correctly, after `QThread::finished` is emitted, the event loop has already stopped running, and if no deferred deletion events exist (i.e. `QObject::deleteLater` hasn't been called), all objects in the thread should have finished processing events as well. So why bother using `QObject::deleteLater` for these objects instead of just manually deleting them? I have no problem with using `QObject::deleteLater`; I'm just making sure my understanding of Qt is correct.

Comment: Are you asking because there's some problem with using deleteLater? Or just for your understanding?

Comment: Just my understanding. I meant to put that in my post, but I forgot. I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QObject::deleteLater` in this case is essentially just erring on the side of caution. There's no reason you couldn't simply `delete` the objects if you're absolutely certain there's no chance the object will be accessed.

In practice though you'll save way more time simply using `QObject::deleteLater` and letting Qt take care of it for you, compared to the hassle of debugging some random-seeming crash during runtime or on exit because there happens to be an access to an object you manually deleted.

Comment: `deleteLater()` isn't a cure-all against dereferencing dangling pointers -- a dangling pointer is just as dangerous after Qt deleted its referent as when your own code did.  Where `deleteLater()` _does_ help (in my experience) is when the method you are executing is being called (directly or indirectly) from a method *of the object you want to delete*. In that scenario, if you just delete the object, you're almost certain to invoke undefined behavior as soon as your method returns and the calling method tries to access a member variable of its (now-deleted) object; `deleteLater()` avoids that.

Comment: That is certainly a valid scenario where it's critical you use `deleteLater()` in place of `delete`. I completely agree it isn't a cure-all, there's inherent risk in referencing a pointer regardless of how you clean up the object. Just for safety in general, after `deleteLater()` or `delete` I always prefer setting the pointer to `nullptr`, and prefacing any access of a pointer with a `nullptr` check. Some places I've worked bake this into their coding standard and I've found it pays off, as unnecessary as it may seem sometimes.

Comment: I also had the thought that connecting `QThread::finished` to existing slots might simply be more convenient or aesthetically pleasing than connecting it to custom functions/functors.